# Chef Shared Ruby Functions or libraries

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

We have a local Ruby Library that we include in a lot of our ruby projects.  It contains a lot of configuration information that would be extremely useful to use in our chef scripts.  This allows us to put all of our configuration in one place, so we don't have to make multiple places everytime we change a database etc.  Trying to keep the code DRY.  That being said, the code are straight ruby functions, not in the chef DSL.

I have been trying to pull the library into Chef, but have found it very difficult.  Which makes me think I'm going against some sort of pattern.

I have tried and didn't work.
    - Add the Ruby Code via require_relative and includes.
    - Add the Ruby Code to it's own cookbook, then wrap the cookbook.
    - Create a local ruby gem (not retrievable via rubygems, or other repo)

What worked:
    - Copying and pasting the code into a cookbook. (but it's not sharable.)

My real question, what is the best way to share this ruby code library amongst many cookbooks?  Depending on the best way, how do you actually do it?, or pointers in the right direction.

thanks.
myles.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Halite](https://github.com/poise/halite) (disclaimer: my project) to convert the gem into a cookbook and then upload it as a cookbook. Then you can depend on it and require stuff from it like normal in your Chef code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cookbook and copy the ruby code into libraries folder of the cookbook. Then it will be loaded by Chef automatically on node, as soon as you include the cookbook into run list.

Could you tell, what exactly you did, and what didn't work when you tried "Add the Ruby Code to it's own cookbook, then wrap the cookbook"?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a ruby library.  Basically, it reads the  ip of the server in opsworks.  Once it gets that it knows what environment it is in, and it will set a hash.  This hash is then used to set the attributes.  This way all the server configurations are stored in one place.

I can put the code in each different cookbook that needs it.  However, I have to duplicate the code in each different cookbook.  I would like to put the code in one place, and include it in each cookbook.  That way if I have to modify it, I only have to do it in one place.

I tried making it a gem, and requiring it with no luck.
I also created a cookbook with nothing but the ruby code in a library.  I then included "depends etc" that cookbook in another and tried to run the library functions, but I couldn't get it to work.

I may have been on the right track, but I stopped before I got it working.

Essentially I want to write a simple ruby code library, that I can use in any cookbook I want.  There must be a way to do this, but I've run into some dead ends.  I'll keep banging my head against the wall.  Eventually, a hole will open up!